# Using my laptop as a USB power supply

Tags: windows, laptop, usb, software-rec, power-supply

I've been using my laptop as a USB charger for my media player (usually an iPod Touch).  Each night, I play an audio-book from my media player (usually iPod Touch), which needs to be charging (via USB).

Is there an **alternate OS** (to Windows) or an extremely **low power setting** for that would allow me to use my laptop **only** as a power supply for my devices?

Comment: http://www.priceangels.com/-s96671.html

Comment: I think an alternative OS is a bit extreme.. I am sure there has to be a window's program somewhere that can do this for you, essentially hibernating your computer or something and still powering devices

Comment: @ekaj It'd be great if that existed... I don't use the laptop for anything else (even though its fully functioning, I just got a new one).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I can't handle an AC or DC power adapter.  Please address the question.

Comment: So then what runs your laptop?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Currently Windows Vista 32-bit

Comment: No, not the OS. The power supply.

Comment: Standard Dell power supply.  You want power ratings?

Comment: If minopret's answer to have to laptop charge the device when in a low power state doesn't work, then I would suggest leaving the computer at the BIOS screen. The USB ports are probably powered so keyboards would work in BIOS mode, and the hard drive will probably spin down because it is idle. I assume everything else would be minimally powered. Some laptops can heat up because the temporary sensors don't ramp up the fans when in BIOS, but if your laptop doesn't have that problem, then the BIOS screen may be the minimal power needed to power the USB ports with the computer on.

Comment: I'm very interested in why you choose this approach. Would you care to share the background?

Comment: Some laptops have powered USB ports that have current even when the machine is turned off. Check your manual.

Comment: @dnbrv  Some USB devices will not charge from a computer that is not running, e.g. my old Sony e-reader & MP3 player  :(

Comment: @dnbrv Mine donesn't.

Comment: @Scott McClenning If I were you, I'd post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 7 there is a setting to permit USB charging during sleep and standby/hibernate: In control panel `Power Options` > `Advanced Settings` > (choose from dropdown) > `USB Settings`, check the box `USB selective suspend setting`.

Info found at: [getting devices in usb port to charge](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/getting-devices-in-usb-port-to-charge/ff0d5242-1f7d-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5?msgId=9c2f5a70-d57d-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5) at Microsoft Answers, Windows; [Re: HP USB power during standby and hibernate](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/HP-USB-power-during-standby-and-hibernate/m-p/241482#M26269) at HP Support Forum.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I edited my question (as it turns out, most nights I use an iTouch).

Answer (score 1):

If @minopret's answer to have to laptop charge the device when in a low power state doesn't work, then I would suggest leaving the computer at the BIOS screen. The USB ports are probably powered so keyboards would work in BIOS mode, and the hard drive will probably spin down because it is idle. I assume everything else would be minimally powered. Some laptops can heat up because the temporary sensors don't ramp up the fans when in BIOS, but if your laptop doesn't have that problem, then the BIOS screen may be the minimal power needed to power the USB ports with the computer on.

Comment: Is there an OS that is effectively BiOS but lets me choose if I want my fans on, and if so, at what power level... a fully customize-able hardware based OS?

Comment: Ideally, the fans speed should be automatic for the protection of the hardware. I've had old laptops that relied on the OS to command the fan speed. Newer laptops seem to have this in hardware. As far as an alternate OS, I can't really think of one that I know could monitor the temperature and command the fans if needed, and be able to disable/power off peripherals (Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, NIC, sound card, video card (in screen saver mode)). You could try a minimal version of Linux, but without something like a "Kill-A-Watt", it would hard to say if/how much power you may be saving.